# Upload images and showing them in a view Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5, image-uploading

I made a function in which I upload images of some products. When I iterate through all my products, I want to show the image too.

The problem is, the image is being uploaded, but I can't present it when i iterate with `@foreach`. I tried in the controller to get the path but it didn't work.

So far I have done this:

In config/filesystems.php I created a custom storage

```
'products' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path('/pictures/uploads/products'),
    ],
```

When I create a new product:

```
<h1>Create new product</h1>
  {!! Form::open(['route' => 'vendor.allproducts', 'files'=>true]) !!}
  <div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('Title', 'Title:') !!}
     {!! Form::text('title',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('File', 'File:') !!}
     {!! Form::file('image') !!}
  </div>
```

When i iterate through my products info:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <tr> 
      .
      .

       <td><img src="{{ $product->imagePath }}"></td>
     </tr>
 @endforeach
```

And in Controller:

```
public function store(){
    $product = Request::all();
    $file = Request::file('image');
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Storage::disk('products')->put($file->getFilename().'.'.$extension,  File::get($file));
    //$product->imagePath = Input::file('image')->getRealPath();
    Auth::user()->products()->create($product);
    return redirect()->route('allproducts');
}
```

Comment: Why is this `//$product->imagePath = Input::file('image')->getRealPath();` commented?

Comment: Because it doesn't work. It is a failed attempt to get the path of the file in $product->imagePath column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Store method will be

```
if(input::hasfile("image")){
        $files = Input::file('image');
        $name = time()."_". $files->getClientOriginalName();
        $image = $files->move(public_path().'/image' , $name);
        $imagefile->image=$name;
    }
         $imagefile->save();
```

And your view should be as

```
<td><img src="{{URL::to('/image/' . $product->image)}}"></td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for not seeing it earlier! Its different from what I was doing but it works! @recovery men can you tell me a way to fix the path of the file in the variable so when that I write `<img src="{{$product->image)}}">`, it will work? I tried `$destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/products/')` and `$product['imagePath'] = '/uploads/products/' . $extension;`
But I want it more dynamically like: `$product['imagePath'] = $destinationPath . $extension;` but this returns me C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\public\/uploads/products/" instead of /uploads/products/image.jpg

Comment: its need to get images from the path where you are moving at time of create even you can also change your path from your store method to store your uploaded images . in above example your images will store in public/images folder